# Suppose $f$ is analytic in the semi-disc then $g$ is analytic in the upper half-plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic in the semi-disc: $|z| \le 1$, $\operatorname{Im}(z) > 0$ and real on the semi-circle $|z| = 1, \operatorname{Im}(z) > 0$. Show that if we set
$$
g(z) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   f(z) & \text{if $|z| \le 1, \operatorname{Im}(z) > 0$} \\ \\
                                   \overline{f\left(\frac{1}{\overline z}\right)} & \text{if $|z| > 1, \operatorname{Im}(z) > 0$} \\
  \end{cases}
$$
then $g$ is analytic in the upper half-plane.
Should I use specific theorems?I know about schwartz reflection principle.  I wonder if it has a straightforward solution.

Comment: I mean... if you know Schwartz Reflection principle then apply it... I don't get the question: have you tried and failed? Because before asking it should be best to try

Comment: @b00nheT I have no idea how to apply the theorem.

Comment: You forgot to conjugate the $z$ in the denominator $\overline{f(1/\bar{z})}$.  This is the reflection principle applied to circular arcs instead of intervals, namely reflect, apply $f$, and reflect again.

Comment: @user10354138 Oh, you are right. I corrected the question

Comment: You can either deduce from [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem), or you can find some [Moebius transformation mapping the circle to the real line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334783/what-m%C3%B6bius-transformation-maps-the-unit-circle-z-z-1-to-the-real-axis) and apply [Schwartz's reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_of_Schwartz).