# Proof that All Triangles can be Inscribed into a Circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Fellow Mathers, I am currently in a Euclidean Geometry class. We are using the [SMSG axioms](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~scott/mat515.fall14/smsg.pdf) to build our geometry. I am struggling in proving the fact that all triangles can be inscribed into a circle, i.e. that...

> $Ɐ$ triangles $ΔABC$, $∃$ a circle $Θ$ such that $A,B,C ∈ Θ$.

Anyone who can provide a proof or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. - SDH

Comment: This question may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16634/prove-that-three-points-are-enough-to-draw-define-one-and-only-one-circle

Comment: In the title "cyclic" is misleading. Periphrasing into "can be inscribed in a circle" would be probably better.

Comment: @JeanMarie Will do. Don’t really know what I’m talking about with the jargon, just saw that terms being used online.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Let be $D$ the intersection point of the perpendicular bisectors of $AC$ and $BC$. You have that

1. $AD=CD$ since $D$ belongs to $s$
2. $CD=BD$ since $D$ belongs to $r$
   Therefore $AD=BD=CD=R $ and the circle of center $D$ and radius $R$ is the required circle.